# Get sum of field in SQL UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I get the SUM of the mutual field here?

```
SELECT first_user_id, mutual
    FROM userprofile_usercontact
UNION ALL
SELECT second_user_id, mutual
    FROM userprofile_usercontact
GROUP BY first_user_id
```

In other words I want to get `SUM(mutual)` for (first_user_id + second_user_id) where mutual = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_id, SUM(u.mutual)
  FROM (SELECT first_user_id AS user_id, mutual
          FROM userprofile_usercontact
        UNION ALL
        SELECT second_user_id AS user_id, mutual
          FROM userprofile_usercontact
       ) AS u
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

The question in the comment asks:

> How would I get rid of entries where mutual = 0?

Using a filter condition, as usual:

```
SELECT u.user_id, SUM(u.mutual)
  FROM (SELECT first_user_id AS user_id, mutual
          FROM userprofile_usercontact
        UNION ALL
        SELECT second_user_id AS user_id, mutual
          FROM userprofile_usercontact
       ) AS u
 WHERE u.mutual != 0   -- or u.mutual <> 0
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

The optimizer might well push the condition down into the UNION queries, so it would execute as if the query was written:

```
SELECT u.user_id, SUM(u.mutual)
  FROM (SELECT first_user_id AS user_id, mutual
          FROM userprofile_usercontact
         WHERE mutual != 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT second_user_id AS user_id, mutual
          FROM userprofile_usercontact
         WHERE mutual != 0
       ) AS u
 GROUP BY user_id;
```

The net result is, of course, the same.

Comment: Thank you, and how would I get rid of entries where mutual = 0 ?

Comment: Treat the sub-select as a table. Use `WHERE u.mutual > 0` to filter out unwanted entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(mutual) sm, user_id FROM
(SELECT first_user_id user_id, mutual
    FROM userprofile_usercontact
    UNION ALL
    SELECT second_user_id, mutual
        FROM userprofile_usercontact
        GROUP BY first_user_id) s 

    GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY sm DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(field) from (
  Select ....
  Union all 
  Select ....
 ) atable
where ....
```